# VS2015 - Nuget - Package incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0

Tags: c#, uwp, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

When I install `SevenzipSharp.Net45` on my Windows 10 UWP app, I receive this message:

> Package SevenZipSharp.Net45 1.0.5 is not compatible with uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0). Package SevenZipSharp.Net45 1.0.5 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.

This message is present also with other package
I had make my UWP App with Framework 4.6 but I had tried also with 4.5 and the problem is the same?

Must I change something?
Thank's a lot.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. This package is not designed for UWP. its for .net 4.5

Comment: Anyone know the link for download the right Package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract 7Zip file in UWP, we can use [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress). This package supports .NETStandard 1.3 so it can be used in UWP apps. To use this library, we can install it [from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress).

> Install-Package sharpcompress

**Please note** to use this package, we also need to use at least **5.2.2** version of [Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/5.2.2) for now.

And following is a simple sample.

```
using (var stream = await (await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\test.7z")).OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
    using (var archive = SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.Open(stream))
    {
        var entry = archive.Entries.First();
        using (var entryStream = entry.OpenEntryStream())
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(entry.Key, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                entryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```